# Getting error while trying to close text writer

Tags: java, file-io

This is my first attempt at file writing to save data in a java program, and i found this solution here on SO, but i am getting an error in my finally statement when i try to close the PrintWriter, saying "out cannot be resolved". 
Much thanks.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class MedConcept {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsoleReader console = new ConsoleReader(System.in);
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("med.txt");
            System.out.println("Name of the medication:");
            String medName = console.readLine();

            System.out.println("The Dosage of the medication:");
            Double medDose = console.readDouble();

            System.out.println("Time of day to take");
            String dayTime = console.readLine();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            out.close();
        }       

    }

}
```

Comment: You're defining out inside the try-block, which is not in the scope of the finally-block. Define out before the try block. Initialize it with `null` if necessary.

Comment: When i take the out outside of the try-block the catch statement is giving me an error telling me : "Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body" @KuluLimpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `out` is declared inside the `try` block which is not visible in the `finally` block. Move the declaration outside and add a check on whether it is null when closing it.

```
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter("med.txt");
        System.out.println("Name of the medication:");
        String medName = console.readLine();

        System.out.println("The Dosage of the medication:");
        Double medDose = console.readDouble();

        System.out.println("Time of day to take");
        String dayTime = console.readLine();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

If you're using Java 7, you can avoid manually closing the `PrintWriter` with a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("med.txt")) {
    ...
} catch() {
    ...
}
```